# facing trouble in run htaccess in root dir and in folder dir

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I am using the following to add support for the `.php` file extension in the URL:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?([a-z]+)$ $1.php [L]
```

For example if the URL is `www.doamin.com/create` then it will call `create.php`.

If I paste my `.htaccess` file in root folder, and call `www.doamin.com/notes/create`, I get an error. If I paste my `.htaccess` file in notes folder, it runs fine.

Why is the file not supported in root?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this before your `RewriteRule`:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.php$
```

When your rule is in the docurment root, it loops indefinitely:

1. URI = notes/create
2. apply rule, URI = notes/create.php
3. apply rule, URI = notes/create.php.php
4. apply rule, URI = notes/create.php.php.php

You need to add a condition so that if the URI ends with `.php` don't apply the rule. Another condition you can add is to check if the URI doesn't exist (e.g. if the create.php file doesn't exist). So you should also add these before your rule:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```